# How can I disable `v` keybinding in less?

Tags: less

When I use `less` and press <kbd>v</kbd> it switches into the currently set editor (Emacs or vim).

> ```
> MISCELLANEOUS COMMANDS
> v    Edit the current file with $VISUAL or $EDITOR.
> ```

Is it possible to prevent this behavior where I don't want current file to be open in the editor?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can disable <kbd>v</kbd> by binding it to `noaction`: add

```
# command
v noaction
```

to `~/.lesskey` (or, if `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is set and you’re using `less` 582 or later, `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/lesskey`), and, if you’re using `less` 581 or older, run `lesskey`.

You can also bind <kbd>v</kbd> to a different command. For example, to make it move down a line instead of opening an editor, use

```
# command
v forw-line
```

instead. (The default binding is `visual`.)

Another way to disable <kbd>v</kbd> in `less` is to set `VISUAL` to `true`:

```
VISUAL=true less foo
```

Pressing <kbd>v</kbd> will then run `true foo`, which will immediately return to `less`.

Answer (score 12):

You may disable the `v` command by setting the environment variables `LESSSECURE` to `1`.

You can set this for new shell sessions with `export LESSSECURE=1` in your shell's initialisation files.

Note, though, that this also disables the `!`, `|`, `:e`, and the `s` command, as well as a few other potentially insecure features.  See the "SECURITY" section in the `less(1)` manual.